# Вставка текста и изображения в docx документ

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется шаблон docx документа, в котором на определенных местах имеется текст *%NAME* или *%PICTURE1*.

Каким образом можно вставить на эти места текст или изображение, и сохранить в виде другого docx документа? (не испортив шаблон)

В гугле слишком громоздкие решения, мне же просто необходимо заметить один текст на другой текст, либо на изображение.

Comment: Не буду писать код сюда,но я решал такую задачу в одном своем проекте уже Можешь пользоваться:) https://yadi.sk/d/MzQSW45_3VgWU6

Comment: Напишите код всё же